# Как проверить доступность файла по его Uri

Tags: android

Перевожу приложение на использование Storage Access Framework. Приложение сохраняет свои настройки в файл который расположен где-либо. Используя `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` получаю uri файла, а так же удерживаю права на него с помощью `takePersistableUriPermission`. Сохраняю `uri.toString()` и прекрасно с ним работаю в фоне.
Теперь приложение устанавливаю на другое устройство и синхронизирую настройки в которых хранится тот самый `uri.toString()`. Теперь при обращении к этому источнику приложение вылетает с ошибкой

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
> com.google.android.apps.docs.storagebackend.StorageBackendContentProvider
> from ProcessRecord{9b012c9 5733:ru.alexeydubinin.holidays/u0a317}
> (pid=5733, uid=10317) requires that you obtain access using
> ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

Пытался обработать при помощи try, но не получается.

```
public static boolean alterDocument(Context context, @NonNull Uri uri, String data) {
    boolean result = false;
    try(ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")){
        if(pfd != null) {
            try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor())) {
                out.write(data.getBytes());
                result = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ignore) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

Как правильно написать этот метод, что бы отловить  момент когда приложение получит вылет? Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте ловить SecurityException а не ошибки ввода вывода. Если вы устанавливаете приложение на другое устройство почему вы думаете что получаете все разрешения?

Comment: @Style-7, я и не думаю, что получаю их. Если по сохраненному uri не найдены никакие данные, то вернется null и будет выполнен запрос на указание файла как раз через `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Попробую отловить SecurityException, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это означает ровно то что написано, а именно права на доступ к файлу вы получите только после отработки `Intent`а `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

Я бы советовал файл после отработки `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` скопировать себе во внутреннее хранилище и дальше уже спокойно с ним работать.

Comment: но я уже получал права на файл при помощи `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` и сохранив его Uri мне нужно спустя какое то время открыть его снова, через `getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor`. Обычно оно так и работает, но время от времени права пропадают и приложение вылетает. Вопрос в том, как отловить этот вылет и уже в этом случае вызвать снова `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`